# How to delete uv maps (UVMap.001), etc?

Tags: uv-image-editor

[image]

I'm using MagicUV and I don't know how these uv maps keep getting created. MagicUV has also stopped working correctly (Copy and pasting is broken now), and I think it has something to do with these uv maps. I can't seem to find a way to delete them, though. Does anyone know how to delete them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, I figured it out. It's located in a different area. The green triangle icon, select the unwanted uv maps from the list there and then hit the minus button.

[image]